# Building a Sheets Emailer

Tags: javascript, html, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

> The Idea:

- User selects “Email” from menu which opens the Google Sidebar.
- It prompts the user to select their field office location with radio buttons and add their additional message for the email body with a text area
- User clicks Submits and “FFO_Email” function runs

“FFO_Email” function will do the following

- Determines the Field Office Location based on the radio selection
- Determines the list of emails based on Field Office Location ('FFO-IS'!A3:A12) and emails to the right in “FFO-IS” sheet ('FFO-IS'!B3:H12)
- Creates email subject
- Creates email body (which will incorporate the additional message from text area in sidebar
- Finally sending email to individuals and displaying the message the email has been sent successfully in the sidebar

> The problems I’m having

The selected radio Field Office Location and Additional Message are not passing to the FFO_Email.gs function. Thus not sending the email to the individuals.

> Sheet can be found here

https://docs.google.com/a/cougars.ccis.edu/spreadsheets/d/1PK18AXMlfC2reKRP7IJWHRT9TEnDzfWa3g-uavgsxUk/edit?usp=sharing

FFO_email.html

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">

  <script>
    function onSuccess(fieldOffice, AdditionalMessage) {
      var div = document.getElementById('fieldOfficeFFO');
      div.innerHTML = 'Email for ' + fieldOffice + ' has been sent successfully.';
    }
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
      .FFO_Email();
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <form id=fieldOfficeFFO>

    <fieldset style="background-color:LightGray;width:250px">

      <div>
        <label for="Field Office Select">Please select your field office below.</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="fieldOfficeFFO" id="fieldOfficeFFO" value="ARK_E_TEXAS">
        <label for="ARK_E_TEXAS">ARK_E_TEXAS</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="fieldOfficeFFO" id="fieldOfficeFFO" value="BORDER_EAST">
        <label for="BORDER_EAST">BORDER_EAST</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="fieldOfficeFFO" id="fieldOfficeFFO" value="BORDER_WEST">
        <label for="BORDER_WEST">BORDER_WEST</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="fieldOfficeFFO" id="fieldOfficeFFO" value="CENTRAL_TEXAS">
        <label for="CENTRAL_TEXAS">CENTRAL_TEXAS</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="fieldOfficeFFO" id="fieldOfficeFFO" value="DALLAS">
        <label for="DALLAS">DALLAS</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="fieldOfficeFFO" id="fieldOfficeFFO" value="FORT_WORTH">
        <label for="FORT_WORTH">FORT_WORTH</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="fieldOfficeFFO" id="fieldOfficeFFO" value="GULF_COAST">
        <label for="GULF_COAST">GULF_COAST</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="fieldOfficeFFO" id="fieldOfficeFFO" value="LOUISIANA">
        <label for="LOUISIANA">LOUISIANA</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="fieldOfficeFFO" id="fieldOfficeFFO" value="NEW_MEXICO">
        <label for="NEW_MEXICO">NEW_MEXICO</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="fieldOfficeFFO" id="fieldOfficeFFO" value="OKLAHOMA">
        <label for="OKLAHOMA">OKLAHOMA</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <br>
    <br>

    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="AdditionalMessage">Additional Message</label>
        <textarea id="AdditionalMessage" rows="3" style="width:250px"></textarea>
      </div>
    </fieldset>

  </form>

  <div class="block">
    <button class="blue" onclick="onSuccess(fieldOfficeFFO,AdditionalMessage)">Submit</button>
    <button onclick="google.script.host.close()">Close</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

FFO_Email.gs

```js
function FFO_Email(fieldOfficeFFO, AdditionalMessage) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('FFO-IS')
  var firstRow = 3;
  var lastRow = 10;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, lastRow, 8);
  var myDate = new Date();
  var hrs = myDate.getHours();

  //Determines the row the Field Office is in
  for (var j = 0; j < dataRange.length; j++) {
    if (dataRange[j][0] == fieldOfficeFFO) {
      Logger.log((j + 1))
      return j + 1;
    }
  }

  //Create the greeting based on the time of day
  var greeting;

  if (hrs < 12)
    greeting = 'Good Morning';
  else if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 17)
    greeting = 'Good Afternoon';
  else if (hrs >= 17 && hrs <= 24)
    greeting = 'Good Evening';


  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];

    var field_Office = fieldOfficeFFO;
    var PT_Director = dataRange.getValues(j, 2);
    var PT_Manager = dataRange.getValues(j, 3);
    var PT_Management_Specialist = dataRange.getValues(j, 4);
    var Area_Supervisory_AM = dataRange.getValues(j, 5);
    var Area_AM = dataRange.getValues(j, 6);
    var SC_Senior_Property_Manager = dataRange.getValues(j, 7);
    var AMS = dataRange.getValues(j, 8);
    var email_Subject = field_Office + " FFO / Income Statement Report is ready for viewing";
    var message_Body = greeting + "," +
      "<br> <br>" +
      "The " + field_Office + " <b>FFO / Income Statement Report is ready for viewing in</b> the <i>AMS Standard Reports - R07 Google Folder</i>" +
      " located at https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0Bx1aKS2V9K-kb0tNLXFfbGtmalE" +
      "<br> <br>" +
      "<br> <br>" +
      //Additional Message from html side added here
      AdditionalMessage +
      "<br> <br>" +
      "Thank you." +
      "<br> <br>" +
      AMS;


    //Send email
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: SC_Senior_Property_Manager + "," + Area_AM + "," + AMS,
      cc: PT_Director + "," + PT_Manager + "," + PT_Management_Specialist + "," + Area_Supervisory_AM,
      replyTo: AMS,
      subject: email_Subject,
      htmlBody: message_Body
    });
    return fieldOfficeFFO
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Radio inputs in the same group can't have the same `id=`.
Giving them the same name attribute is ok if that's how you want to group them.
Textarea has no `name=` attribute at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few changes that need to be made:

I'd create a new function for the submission, I'm calling it `sendInputInfo()`:

Script Tag:

```
<script>
  function sendInputInfo() {
    console.log('sendInputInfo ran!');//Open browsers console to see print out
    //Get the form information to be sent
    var theFormElement = document.getElementById('fieldOfficeFFO');

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
      .FFO_Email(theFormElement);
  };

  function onSuccess(fieldOffice, AdditionalMessage) {
    div.innerHTML = 'Email for ' + fieldOffice + ' has been sent successfully.';
  };
</script>
```

Change the `onclick` attribute:

```
<button class="blue" onclick="sendInputInfo()">Submit</button>
```

Note that there are no values in the parenthesis being sent to the function.  That's not needed.  The form is being retrieved in the `sendInputInfo()` function.

Currently, the code is not passing any information to the server.  There is nothing in the parenthesis of the server function:

Currently:

```
.FFO_Email();
```

There needs to be something in the parenthesis:

```
.FFO_Email(theFormElement);
```

Your `.gs` code has two arguments in the parenthesis.  Apps Script will only accept one input on the server side if it is a form object.  So, you'll need to change the function to:

```
function FFO_Email(theFormObject) {
  Logger.log('theFormObject: ' + theFormObject);//Should be an object
  Logger.log('theFormObject.fieldOfficeFFO: ' + theFormObject.fieldOfficeFFO);

  for (var key in theFormObject) {//Loop through all the data in the form
    Logger.log('key: ' + key);
    Logger.log('value: ' + theFormObject[key]);
  };
```

Comment: I read through your answer and made the changes but still no luck. I am curious on where the selected radio and the additional message is passed from the HTML side to the Google Apps Script side

Comment: You'll need to debug your code from start to finish.  You need to figure out how much of the code is working, and where it stops working.  Everything beyond where it's not working can't be trusted.  See the updated answer at the end.  You need to know for sure what the server is receiving for data.  Bryan P is right about the `id's`.  Delete all the `id="fieldOfficeFFO"` attributes, they are useless.  Apps Script will **NOT** allow the id to be passed in the form object, only names.

Comment: I have made the changes that you suggested and read more into the changes that you made. The script will now send the email to the list of individuals but the form is not saying that the email was sent. Additionally, I have made more changes that no longer fit the code of what I originally posted but am still seeking the same result. Should I start a new question or should I update my question?